# How to pass Ant target names in the jenkins email report?

Tags: jenkins, ant, target

I am using the editable email-ext plugin. I get emails with default content in the subject and email body. But I need the name of the Ant target that was executed in the email body and subject line.
[image]

Comment: Are you often editing the job configuration to change the Ant target? A better approach would be to make this build parameterized, and then you can reference the same parameter in your Invoke Ant step and your Email notification.

Comment: Yes, I do change the target. I just edit the job and build it. It goes and sits into the queue since there will be many suites in queue in regression periods. So I thought if suite name was in email report it would be good. But you know what? I could just add the name of that suite in the content as I am preparing the job! But its one extra step though.

Comment: In that case, again I would suggest you check out parameterized builds. When you start the build manually, you can provide a value for a given parameter, or you can provide it in a curl command in the URL https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

Comment: Agreed. I will try that. Thank you CAustin